# Unclosed quote in a CSS block

Tags: css, syntax, language-lawyer

This snippet is red on Firefox and blue on Chrome. Who is right?

```css
* { background: red; '}
* { background: blue; }
```

[§4.1.6 Blocks](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#block) says:

> Single (`'`) and double quotes (`"`) must also occur in matching
>   pairs, and characters between them are parsed as a string.

But if `'` or `"` do not occur in matching pairs, how should the syntax error be handled?

Comment: I would vote for Chrome since red's block is the one with the unmatched quote, but that's just, like, my opinion, man.

Comment: I prefer Chrome's way of handling this, but I'm not sure either Chrome or Firefox are "right" - instead I think the css is just wrong.

Comment: @TheLeggett Yes, the CSS is wrong, and shouldn't be used. I'm just curious to know if the spec defines what should happen in those cases.

Comment: Chrome 53 is red, they fixed the bug.

Comment: Sad... I think the Chrome's behavior was more helpful, salvaging as much CSS as possible even after the error, while Firefox would just throw it away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By my reading of [4.2 Parsing Errors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors), and the so-called "*rules for matching pairs*" the construct:

```
* { background: red; '}
* { background: blue; }
```

Should be read as:

```
* { background: red; ...<EOF> }
```

That is, *everything* in the file after the `'}` is going to be discarded because there's no matching `}` for the `{` in that line (because there's always another `{` first before another `}` is seen), so it will not get closed until the end of the file implicitly closes it.

Of course, it's really complicated, so I could be wrong...

---

Further reading through the CSS21 grammar seems to confirm this.  Basically, there are two effects in play here:

1. An unmatched `'` will cause everything to the end of the current line to be ignored.  And,
2. An unmatched `{` will cause everything to the end of the file to be parsed as though it is still part of the same Block of Declarations.

So basically, #1 causes the closing `}` to be lost.  And #2 probably causes everything after it to be lost because it cannot be parsed as a valid declaration with the block (because the `{..}` nesting count will always be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

While Chrome simply ignores the line without complaining, Firefox stops processing the CSS any further and logs a warning (this applies at least to Chrome 41.0.2.. and FF 36.0.1 on Mac OS X Yosemite):

`Found unclosed string ''}'.  Expected declaration but found ''}'.  Skipped to next declaration.`

And though the warning says `Skipped to next declaration.`, FF actually does not in my case (added a bit of css before and after the code provided).

Both is not a very good solution in my opinion since the web relies in big parts on CSS these days, so neither should a Browser ignore a syntax error nor should it stop processing the css altogether.

I know Safari wasn't mentioned in the question and I'm not really a big fan of it, but here's what it does: Log a warning, skip the line and process the rest of the file. This is what I would expect.

Just my 0.02..